# Glide recyclerview loading duplicate image

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a `recyclerview` with `diffutil`. Already I using `Glide` to load images inside the `ImageViews`.

on the `onBindViewHolder` I call my function it's called `loadImage(holder.view,item)`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)

    onLoadImage(holder.view, item)
}
```

In my loadImage I load the image inside the view.

```
 private fun loadImage(view: View, item: MyItemModel) {
        Timber.i("load item's image id: ${item.id} image is: ${item.image}")

        Glide.with(context)
                .asDrawable()
                .load(item.image)
                .into(view.main_image)
    }
```

It works good, but when first time when It's loading the image than I swipe in the list, and the Images are shows like this:

[image]

So the Images are duplicated, but the last two image is different. It happens only if I swipe fast when It's loading.
Log:

```
I/MyListAdapter: load image into : 6 image is: [B@25d0674
I/MyListAdapter: load image into : 7 image is: [B@e64ced4
I/MyListAdapter: load image into : 8 image is: [B@b384734
```

This is a Custom View. Context is that's view's context.

So the Images are different. 
What is the problem?

Any suggestion?

Comment: try loading image inside **onBindViewHolder** itself

Comment: is there any difference?

Comment: yes, when you try to scroll fast then onBindViewHolder will be called multiple times within seconds. and it loads the recycled image as on the imageview and then try to load it into the imageview which takes time. you can use **placeholder** in this case.

Comment: Take a look at  this thread: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1275

Comment: see this: http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/331/com/bumptech/glide/load/engine/DiskCacheStrategy.html

Comment: I think it is memory problem. I created a list with 8 item. Every item has a "byte[]" image. Maybe this is the problem. Hmm

Comment: Did you find the solution for this  problem ? If yes, please share the answer. I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I know its late but hope it will help someone. Override these two methods in your adapter.

```
  @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
}

  @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 return position;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. How and Why ? Can you share the explanation please?

Comment: I can not understand what you say @MiniChip

Comment: Also having this issue with SDK v32. Just overriding getItemViewType seems to fix it for me but would also like to know why. Does the parent RecyclerView.Adapter cache the position that causes this to happen or something?

Comment: I think this solution work because RecyclerView will not recycle view anymore. as each item is one type.
If RecyclerView dont recycle the view (which contain ImageView inside), then duplicated image will not happened
This solution may work if your RecyclerView dont have many items, but it may a problem with performance if your RecyclerView have more items

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the image before loading a new one in your `loadImage` method:

```
view.main_image.setImageBitmap(null)
Glide.with(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image can come from both local drawable or remote url.
There is a chance that you will get duplicated image. Basically, your local image may be override by remote image.
Then before loading local drawable, you should cancel loading process which happened on this image

You can find the example here
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (isLoadingRemoteImage) {
        ...
    } else {
        Glide.with(context).clear(holder.imageView);
        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(specialDrawable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(context)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions().frame(1000000L)) // Set the time in microseconds
        .load(videoPath)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoriesViewHolder, position: Int){

    Glide.with(context)
        **.setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions().frame(1000000L)) //add 
         this line only if you are using gif**
        .load(imgList[position])
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .into(holder.imageview)

    //Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(imgList[position]).into(holder.imageview)
}
```

this code ensure that the loaded image is not stored in memory (skipMemoryCache(true)) or on disk (diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)), so it's fetched fresh each time from the source.