# RecyclerView Item with Duplicate Image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-glide

I have created a Staggered List using RecyclerView v28.0.0 in combination with Glide Image Library v4.9.0.

Please do not mark this question as duplicate because I referred below items before posting this question:

- [Glide recyclerview loading duplicate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701438/glide-recyclerview-loading-duplicate-image/52701679)
  [RecyclerView duplicating items some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393720/recyclerview-duplicating-items-some-time)
  http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html#listview-and-recyclerview

I create an Adapter using DataBoundListAdapter that includes diff callback as well.

To make sure each recycler view item is picking up a unique ID, I'd use hashmap as:

```
override fun bind(binding: ItemStockBinding, item: InventoryProductWithSKU, position: Int) {
 mContext?.let {
            Glide.with(it)
                    .load(mIdImageMap[item.inventoryProductEntity.id])
                    .apply(RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .error(R.drawable.place_holder))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                    .into(binding.layoutProductImage)
        } }
```

And, To handle the case if Image not present, I'd:

```
 Glide.with(mContext!!).clear(binding.layoutProductImage)
 binding.layoutProductImage.setImageDrawable(null)
```

This issue is recurring at most of the places in our app. Please suggest any workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: As mentioned in title, some of the Items of list is showing duplicate image.